# PHP 5.2 Virtual-like static methods

Tags: php, static, virtual

Here is my situation:  I have a PHP base class that looks something like this:

```
class Table {
  static $table_name = "table";
  public function selectAllSQL(){
    return "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name;
  }
}
```

And a subclass that is like this:

```
class MyTable extends Table {
  static $table_name = "my_table";
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do:

```
MyTable::selectAllSQL()
```

I get:

```
"SELECT * FROM table"
```

instead of my desired result,

```
"SELECT * FROM my_table"
```

It looks like this can be accomplished in php 5.3 using [late static bindings](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/02/php-static-for-self-what-else-for.html), but is there any way I can accomplish this behavior in PHP 5.2.x?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. That's why LSB was added to 5.3. Instantiation is the way to go, in this place, along with a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Yeh late static binding is the way to go. Maybe you are on PHP 5.3 by now.
Here is how it should look then:

Change

```
class Table {
  static $table_name = "table";
  public function selectAllSQL(){
    return "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name;
  }
}
```

to

```
class Table {
  static $table_name = "table";
  public function selectAllSQL(){
    return "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the class of cause is an option!

```
<?php
abstract class Table {
    protected $table_name;
    public function selectAllSQL() {
        return 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table_name;
    }
}

class MyTable extends Table {
    protected $table_name = 'my_table';
}

$my_table = new MyTable();
echo $my_table->selectAllSQL(); // Will output "SELECT * FROM my_table"
```

If you have to keep static than reimplementation is the only way to go in PHP < 5.3:

```
<?php
abstract class Table {
    protected static $table_name = 'table';
    public static function selectAllSQL() {
        return self::selectAllSQLTable(self::$table_name);
    }
    public static function selectAllSQLTable($table) {
        return 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;
    }
}

class MyTable extends Table {
    protected static $table_name = 'my_table';
    public static function selectAllSQL() {
        return self::selectAllSQLTable(self::$table_name);
    }
}

class MyOtherTable extends Table {
    protected static $table_name = 'my_other_table';
    public static function selectAllSQL() {
        return self::selectAllSQLTable(self::$table_name);
    }
}

echo MyTable::selectAllSQL(); // Will output "SELECT * FROM my_table"
echo MyOtherTable::selectAllSQL(); // Will output "SELECT * FROM my_other_table"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to instantiate the classes?